# PHP SWITCH entering DEFAULT even if there is a valid CASE?

Tags: php, default, switch-statement

I have this SWITCH block:

```
switch ($_GET['page']) {

    case "listaOferteTest":
        include("php_views/lista_oferte_test.php");
    break;

    case "categorieOferte":
        include("php_views/categorie_oferte.php");
    break;

    case "pagina":
        include("php_views/pagina.php");
    break;

    default:
        include("php_views/page_not_found_redirect.php");
    break;
}
```

and some php links [they are dinamicaly generated, but i'll paste the html]:

```
<a href='/pagina/termeni-si-conditii/'>
Termeni si conditii
</a>
<a href='/pagina/informatii-utile/'>
Informatii utile
</a>
<a href='/pagina/contact/'>
Contact
</a>
```

I have a .htaccess where i treat the link like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?page=$1&subPage=$2&subSubPage=$3 [L]
```

The problem: When I tested the links above I noticed a strange behavior - from about 10 clicks on random links one gets also the default. How is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of $glob['page'] when it hit default errantly?

Comment: You should include a die(var_dump($glob['page'])); on your default case.

Comment: Can you confirm that the value is being trimmed before it hits the case?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not trimm the value. I should check that!

Comment: I have edited the question because it seemed that it was not enought info there. Now you can see how that var that is being "switched" is getting values.. The frustrating part is that it doesn't happen all the time..

Comment: $_GET['page'] is not always equal to 'pagina'. This is the only possible solution - check the rest of your code for a bug, or add die($_GET['page); to the default case.

Comment: Thanks, MW, I shall do that !

Comment: I got the values witch GET['page'] gets: those are "favicon.ico" and "images" (from ~10 times when problem appears, ~8 times the var gets "favicon.ico"). The last one is a folder of mine, but I do not use any favicon.ico explicitly.

Comment: You need to configure your rewrite rule to ignore .ico and image requests using RewriteCond

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to get the debugger out and step through the code so you can see exactly what's going on. If you don't have a debugger installed (why not? you should, it'll change your life!) or if you can't recreate the problem with a debugger given it's seemingly random nature, then next best thing would be to add some logging to the default block so you can work out why it's getting there. My guess would be that $glob['page'] doesn't match 'pagina' exactly; maybe it's got a leading/trailing space or slash, or maybe it's empty because there's a bug in how that value is being extracted. Something like [Monolog](http://nelm.io/blog/2011/07/monolog-1-0-released/) would do the job in terms of logging.

Comment: Thanks! I will document about that kind of debuggers!

Answer (score -2):

Then u can use, `if`'s instead of `switch`.

For ex.

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   if($_GET['page']=='something') {...}
   if($_GET['page']=='something2') {...}
   ...
}
```

Comment: I guess I can do that, thanks! But I would still like to understand what is happening with this..

Comment: Thx, Tural! The problem is not the fact that I am not familiar with the php Control Structures.. A reason for using switch is the lighter/less code.